# Basis for the rank and null space of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to determine if the following statement is true or false:

"There exists $T\in \mathcal{L}(R^4\to R^2)$ such that $\text{null } (T = \{(0,0,0,x):x\in R\}$.

I marked that this statement as false, and it is. My logic was that the null space has dimension of at least 2 and thus cannot be what is defined above.

Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your conclusion, null space has dimension at least 2.

Comment: And am I correct in that dimension this transformation may have a null space greater than 2?

Comment: of course from 2 to 4!